# UITableViewCell element no longer accessible via [cell.contentView viewWithTag] when scrolled down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create expand/collapse cell. On every cell, it has subview of `UIView` for border bottom. If expanded, the border should also go to bottom of the cell. It is working fine on initial load of the cells, however, when I scroll down, the border is no longer going to the bottom.

I am adjusting the border originY via `taskOptionsExpand` method. That method is getting the border view via `[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2]`.

Code below:

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.selectedIndexPath = nil;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (UITableView *)tableView
{

    if (!_tableView) {
        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];

        _tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        _tableView.delegate = self;
        _tableView.dataSource = self;
        _tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

        [_tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        [_tableView addSubview:self.tableRefreshControl];

    }

    return _tableView;
}


# pragma mark - table view delegates
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self.selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
        return 80;
    }else{
        return 50;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    // text view
    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 50)];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    view1.tag = 0;
    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view1.frame];
    title.text = @"Lorem ipsum";
    title.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [view1 addSubview:title];

    // options view
    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];
    view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    view2.tag = 1;

    // border bottom
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, 49, self.view.frame.size.width-40, 1);
    if ([self.selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
        frame.origin.y = 79; //expand
    } else {
    }
    UIView *border = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    border.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    border.tag = 2;

    cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:view1];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:view2];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:border];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self.selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
        [self taskOptionsExpand:NO indexPath:indexPath];
        self.selectedIndexPath = nil;
    } else {
        [self taskOptionsExpand:YES indexPath:indexPath];
        [self taskOptionsExpand:NO indexPath:self.selectedIndexPath];
        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    }

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

- (void) taskOptionsExpand:(BOOL) expand indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIView *border = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    NSLog(@"border: %@", border);
    if (expand) {
        border.frame = CGRectMake(20,  79, self.view.frame.size.width-40, 1);
    }else{
        border.frame = CGRectMake(20,  49, self.view.frame.size.width-40, 1);
    }

}
@end
```

Comment: Once you scroll down a previous cell will be reused - and you are adding the views again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When scrolling the `table view`, the cell is `dequeued` to get `reusable cell` and as `reusable cell` will already have `viewWithTag 2` *(since it was added when the cell being reused was created)* so adding `another view with tag 2` will create the issues like above. To overcome the above issue you should remove the earlier added `viewWithTag 2` and than re-add the view with the same tag, like-

```
    // remove (previously added) border if it exists
    UIView *border = nil;
    border = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    if(border)
          [border removeFromSuperview];

    // again create border view
```

Update your  `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: method as

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

        // text view
        UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, self.view.frame.size.width-20, 50)];
        view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        view1.tag = 0;
        UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:view1.frame];
        title.text = @"Lorem ipsum";
        title.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [view1 addSubview:title];

        // options view
        UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];
        view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        view2.tag = 1;

        // border bottom
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, 49, self.view.frame.size.width-40, 1);
        if ([self.selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
            frame.origin.y = 79; //expand
        } else {
        }

        UIView *border = nil;
        border = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
        if(border)
              [border removeFromSuperview];

        border = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        border.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        border.tag = 2;

        cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:view1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:view2];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:border];

        // release your allocated instances after adding them
        [view1 release];
        [view2 release];
        [border release];

        return cell;
    }
```

Also you should `release` your `subviews` which you have `allocated` like `view1, view2, border` after adding them to the cell's content view as

```
[view1 release];
[view2 release];
[border release];
```

This will make there retain count from 2 to 1 and when the cell is deallocated than they will be removed from there parent which is cell.

Comment: setting border to nil and removing from subview did the trick! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Table views re-use cells. When a cell is scrolled offscreen it is added to a queue, and will be re-used for the next cell to be scrolled onscreen. That means your configuration code in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method will be run again on the same cell multiple times at different indexPaths. Since you're just adding your `border` view every time your configuration code runs, they will stack one on top of the other. When you call `viewWithTag:` you will only get one of the multiple views you've added.

The correct approach is to create a custom cell (subclass of `UITableViewCell`) with properties for each subview that needs to be configured (`IBOutlet`s if using xibs/storyboard), so that they can be accessed.